# GWT - Copy & Paste ZeroClipboard

Tags: gwt, clipboard, copy-paste, zeroclipboard

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317052/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-with-gwt).
I need to do a clipboard system in my gwt web application.

ZeroClipboard there is no longer on GoogleCode, and i have downloaded it from GitHub, but this guide doesn't work.
Any one can help me?

This is my situation:

Home.html  (in the same directory i have ZeroClipboard.js and ZeroClipboard.swf)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
```

MyPage.java

```
   -
   -
   -
    final Anchor copy = new Anchor("Copy");
    copy.getElement().setId("copyId");
    glueCopy("Hello World");
    add(copy);

  }

 public static native void glueCopy(String text) /*-{
  var clip = new $wnd.ZeroClipboard.Client();
  clip.setText(text);
  clip.glue('copyId');
}-*/;
```

Nothing happen when i click the anchor.

Comment: What did you try and what error did you encounter!!!

Comment: I have update my question with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the problem my self.
Flash security policy doesn't permit the execute from localhost.

Comment: @nap-gab can you elaborate a bit ? Struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Simply add the flash file not from a local directory, but from a URL ( no  file://zeroclipboard.swf , but http://localhost/zeroclipboard.swf for example)