# How to copy some text to system clipboard?

Tags: gwt, clipboard, gwt2

I have a string and an image. If the user clicks on that image, then that string should be copied to the system clipboard. I have to do this using GWT.
How to copy that string to system clipboard using GWT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy to clipboard with GWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317052/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-with-gwt)